# Attacker in a key exchange

Tags: authentication, keys, key-exchange, protocol-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following question:

> 1. $X(A) \rightarrow B:(A,N_X)$
> 2. $B \rightarrow X(S):(B,((A,N_X,T_B),K_{BS}),N_B)$
> 3. $X(A) \rightarrow B:(((A,N_X,T_B),K_{BS}),(N_B,N_X))$
>
> Give two very good reasons why this attack works, in terms of the properties of the messages being exchanged and their content.

$X$ is the attacker in this case.

$A$ and $B$ are the names of two agents, $S$ is the name of a trusted server, $N_X$ denotes a nonce created  by entity $X$, $T_X$ denotes a timestamp created by entity $X$, $K_{XY}$ denotes a key shared between entities $X$ and $Y$

If anyone can help at all, I would greatly appreciate someone going through this question with me step by step.

From this I have understood that $B$ relays the encrypted message back and thinks everything is okay. The attacker doesn’t care about verifying the message. It gets the key and communicates with $B$ where $B$ thinks it is $A$ who has got the key through the server.

I just want to make sure that i have understood it correctly.

Comment: I think it would help if you explained the notation used in the question. As is it does not make much sense to me at least, and I am afraid others might have the same problem.

Comment: @GuutBoy Updated it explaining the values, sorry about that.

Comment: I suppose it helps a little but it still does not make a lot of sense to me. What does the arrows mean? What does X(A) mean? What is the protocol (assuming we are talking about a protocol) supposed to do? Try to imagine someone who did not take the course you are taking/read the book you are reading, and explain your question so that person would understand it.

Comment: Well its a security protocol, i dont know any better way to explain it. Its quite similar to this http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/what-does-this-authentication-protocol-achieve-and-what-information-is-shared

Comment: @GuutBoy : $\;\;\;$ The arrows mean sends to. $\:$ X(A) means the adversary while pretending to be A. $\hspace{.58 in}$

Comment: @Bimal : $\:$ What do A and B output as their keys? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Surely you were not born knowing what this notation means. If you understand it couldn't you try to explain it? I have never seen it before, I do not think it is some kind of universally understood language. If so, I would still like to learn it.

Comment: Isn't this just an attack trace on Needham–Schroeder?  The kind you can find with proverif, CPSA, or any protocol verification tool worth its salt.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I think you are right and understand the concept but i dont understand why the attack works, the explanation i have given i believe is in theory true but need someone to verify that.

Comment: @RickyDemer Not sure on the output.

Comment: It looks like the notation for symmetric encryption in this is: $(X,K)$ for plaintext $X$ and key $K$. It is an awful notation tho, because it should either be something like $E(X,K)$ or $(X)_K$ to be less confusing. And the same notation is used to denote tuples.. guess what is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this notation "$(A,N_X,T_B),K_{BS}$" isn't correct and must be transcripted as "$(A,N_X,T_B).K_{BS}$", which could be interpreted as the resulting cipherText of "$(A,N_X,T_B)$ under the Key $K_{BS}$".
Under these conditions, we could try to understand that the attacker X begin by impersonating A, by sending to B the plainText $(A,N_X)$

- X: Impersonating A:    X(A) -> $(A,N_X)$
- B: Ask the Server to generate a shared key for A and B, But the message is intecepted by the Attacker who doesn't know the Master Key $K_{BS}$
- The attacker then return back the initial cipherText to B, who can easilly decrypt as he knows its shared Key $K_{BS}$ with the trusted third part.

But there is a problem, this protocol doesn't work, because there is no generation of shared Key by the Server for A and B, and then B after checking the existence of Nonce and TimeStamp, and the absence of shared Key, must logically abort the session, under the assumption that a master Key is never and NEVER send in a plainText.